# Using list comprehension and groupby to subset a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I struggle to apply list comprehension and the groupby function to subset a Pandas dataframe.

My dataframe has a column "patid" which contains a list of patient IDs e.g,. 25001. A patient (25001) will have multiple rows. So, further to that example, a dataframe with 10,000 rows mmay only hold data for 10 patients. I would like to take the list `patidList` and return a dataframe with only the rows in which the value in the column "patid" matches one of the patids in the `patid` column of the dataframe.

I've already subsetted the dataframe using this code which I know is a bit of a bottleneck in terms of speed. I've significantly reduced the size of the lists and dataframes in this example for exercise purposes only:

```
class TestClass():

    def __init__(self):
        dictExample = {
            "patid" : ["25001", "25001", "25001", "999", "999"],
            "interesting_stuff" : ["a","b","c","d","e"]
        }
        self.ioDF = pd.DataFrame(dictExample)

    def someMethod(self):
        patidList = ["25001"]
        reducedDF = self.ioDF.loc[self.ioDF['patid'].isin(patidList)]

testClass = TestClass()
testClass.someMethod()
```

However, it has been suggested to me that I may see a speed up if I use list comprehension and groupby function. I'm not sure how to do this. Please note: I'm interested in speed here. I'm already running this over multiple cores. Even if there is a fraction of a speed up from something like a list to a tuple, that would contribute.

Comment: can you include a reproducible example please

Comment: `loc`+`isin` should be faster than a list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

try to do the following:

```
Datdaframe[dataframe[“patid”].isin(patidList)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm happy to give this a try, I'm just wondering what is the motivation behind removing (or keeping) the .loc notation?